# How do I patch these sections of concrete driveway meeting the house?

Tags: concrete, driveway

Where my driveway meets my house there were two sections of loose concrete that were deteriorating and making a mess.  I removed the loose concrete and discovered that those sections were placed on top of other concrete that I am guessing is the footer of those outside walls of the house.   These missing sections go down 2 1/2 - 3 inches.  How would I go about repairing these sections in a manner that would last.  Do I need to tie the new concrete into the existing footer concrete that is there?  What about the joints between the old and new concrete?  I am a noob with any type of concrete work so any help or advice on how to fix this is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add new concrete to it.
There are a few things you need to do:

1. Clean all dirt and dust from the patch hole.
2. Use a bonding agent to help new and old concrete bond together
   otherwise the new patch just "floats" (you brush this on the old concrete but can also add it to the cement mix as per the product directions to help prevent cracking)
3. Mix and pour the cement.
4. Once cured, Seal the edges of the patch

Bonding agent:

[image: Bonding agent]

Concrete crack sealer:

[image: Concrete crack sealer]

Answer (score 1):

I'd fill the hole up with water using a hose pipe, and let the water overflow. That will carry out any dust/crud which will prevent the concrete bonding properly. Then simply make a strong set of concrete, but make sure you don't under estimate how much you will need as having to go back to your builders merchants will just will a) be a pain b) make the concrete break up again a lot sooner.

I'd always buy too much supplies, most builders merchants will gladly refund any used sealed bags.